# Upgrade Windows Server 2008 to R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to in-place upgrade my Windows Server 2008 SP1 (64bit) to 2008 R2.

Is this supported? Where can I find more information on this process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a supported upgrade path.

If you did a web search for "Upgrade to 2008 R2", you would inevitably have seen [this link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff968983(v=ws.10)) which has all of the considerations and known-issues with in-place upgrading to 2008 R2.